# Reload With Docker and Flask on Windows 10 Home Machine

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-toolbox

I am unable to get Flask to notice changes to my code and reload, making it super hard to program iteratively.

My system: I am using a PC with Windows 10 Home to run Docker Toolbox (regular docker does not work on Windows 10 Home).

My code:

**DockerFile**

```
FROM python:3.4-alpine
RUN  pip install flask-security flask-sqlalchemy
RUN pip install requests
ADD . app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app/app.py"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
```

**app/app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
# Create app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'
# Bcrypt is set as default SECURITY_PASSWORD_HASH, which requires a salt
app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = 'super-secret-random-salt'

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return 'hello world'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

(I've edited this a little bit to be concise, and not give away what I'm doing :) )

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. If not, I ran into this old ticket for VirtualBox where the situation sounds eerily similar. (https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14920) If this is my issue, what is a good solution or workaround? (I'm not looking to buy a new machine or OS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part:

```
volumes:
 - .:/code
```

You are mapping the `/code` in your container to the current directory. But your `workdir` is set to `/app`.

```
ADD . app
WORKDIR /app
```

So you don't need to add the `app.py` file to your `workdir` in your container, you just need to map the volume from current directory in your host machine to the `/app` directory in your container.

So, you need to change:

```
volumes:
 - .:/code
```

to:

```
volumes:
 - .:/app
```

in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

And remove the below line in your `Dockerfile` file:

```
ADD . app
```

Comment: @user7097722 did this automatically detect changes or did you need to restart the container each time?